# The right way of creating custom control composited from multiple controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm working on creating this control:

[image]

I found that a graphical representation would describe the control more than the code:
[image]

and here how I call it:

```
<local:MagicalButton Content="Watch Now" SubTitle="Movie: " FontSize="10" FontStretch="Condensed" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource newBtn}" 
x:Name="togg" ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}"/>
```

So the `ToggleButton` is the base class of the control that I'm overriding its Template, but this would be unfair because the control consists of three equal parts (in functionality and responsibilities):

- ToggleButton (or may be Expander)
- ListBox
- Button (doesn't exit)

The current implementation has one pros:
that I can animate the height of the list box whenever the ToggleButton's IsChecked changed, as the ListBox lies in the ToggleButton's Template:

```
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="0" To="90" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="lstBx" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="60" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotRect" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="90" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="lstBx" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="60" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

But has some cons:

- I can't define a button that is bound to the selected item from the ListBox (it's difficult and complicated)
- I can't limit the toggled area to the triangle area, so the right part of the control still functions as a toggle button and can't assign a special function to it (a button that has click handler bound to the selected item).

So I thought to restructure the control and changing the base class to be more generic `ContentControl`:

[image]

but now I don't have control on the ListBox from the ToggleButton, and that put me on a barrier that separating each control in a generic container may impact the communication between them (contiguous parts can't communicate with each other, but higher controls can communicate with lower controls - in the previous implementation, the ToggleButton and ListBox, but now I don't have control over the ListBox's properties from the Toggle Button and similarly the button cannot be bound to the ListBox's selected item)

so here what I want to achieve:
- first off; keeping the same style
- the left part is a toggle button that can only animate the ListBox's height
- the right part is a Button that bound to the selected item from the ListBox

To summarize, the main problem is what's is the most suitable base control that I can override its template to contain all these three controls, and how can I structure it so I can achieve the communication between them:
[image]

I tried to describe the problem in detail as much as I can, hope find some help

here's the first code implementation:
https://gist.github.com/mshwf/b30364049d1d8291a877e7a9a574d4dc

and the new implementation:
https://github.com/mshwf/WPFTest/blob/master/WPFTest/MagicButton.xaml

Comment: To me it looks more like a ComboBox or SplitButton (some extended WPF libraries have such things).

Comment: Check DropDownButtons from [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/controls/split_dropdownbutton.html)

Comment: Actually, I'm doing it for fun not for an urgent purpose